# what't the meaning of the query in my code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I use the mongodb to fetch the collection which named froggers,but i don't know the meaning of the variable named query.who can explain the meaning of function for me

```
exports.get = function get(username, callback) {
  mongodb.open(function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    // 获取 froggers 集合
    db.collection('froggers', function(err, collection) {
      if (err) {
        mongodb.close();
        return callback(err);

      // 查找 user 属性为 username 的文档，如果 username 是 null 则匹配全部
      var query = {};
      if (username) {
        query.user = username;
      }
      collection.find(query).sort({time: -1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        mongodb.close();
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        }
        // 封裝 froggers 为 Frogger 对象
        var froggers = [];   //定义frogger数组对象

        docs.forEach(function(doc, index) {
          var frogger = new Frogger(doc.user, doc.post, doc.time);
          froggers.push(frogger);
        });
        callback(null, posts);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: `query` is just an object, that might stay empty, or get a property `user` with a specific user name to look for assigned. And then this object is used as a "filter" in querying the DB. If it's empty, `collection.find(query)` will return all records, and if it has a user set it will only return records where the `user` value matches the given one.

Answer (score 0):

the query variable is an object containing the field user.
that field get the value of the username variable.
it was constructed in order to fit the collection.query function.
now this query will fetch all the collection in which `user = username.`
so if `username='albert'` the query will strat :

```
collection.find({user:'alebrt'})
```

...........

Comment: why the query variable initialized with a empty brace?what the brace stand for?

Comment: {} are the representation of hash/object in javascript. You should learn the basics of the langage first …